# Which queue is used for -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:afterDelay]?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsrunloop, performselector

I recently ran into an issue where deferred selectors weren't firing (an NSTimer and methods called with `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay`).

I've read Apple's documentation, and it does mention in the special considerations area,

> This method registers with the runloop of its current context, and depends on that runloop being run on a regular basis to perform correctly. One common context where you might call this method and end up registering with a runloop that is not automatically run on a regular basis is when being invoked by a dispatch queue. If you need this type of functionality when running on a dispatch queue, you should use dispatch_after and related methods to get the behavior you want.

This makes perfect sense, except for the runloop of its current context part.  I found myself confused regarding which runloop it's actually going to.  Would it be the thread's main runloop that processes all events, or could it be a different one without our knowledge?

For instance, if I hit a breakpoint before calling performSelector inside a block that is being called as a CoreAnimation completion block, the debugger shows execution is on the main thread.  However, calling `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` never actually runs the selector.  This makes me think that call is effectively registering with the runloop associated with the CoreAnimation framework, so regardless of the `performSelector` call being executed on the main thread, if the CoreAnimation doesn't poll its runloop, the operation isn't executed.

Replacing this call inside that block with `performSelectorOnMainThread:WithObject:waitUntilDone` fixes the problem, but I've had a hard time convincing a colleague that this is the root cause.

**Update:  I was able to trace back the origin of the issue to a UIScrollViewDelegate callback.  It makes sense that when a UI delegate callback is invoked that the main runloop would be in UITrackingRunLoopMode.  But at that point, the handler will queue a block on a background queue and from there execution will jump across a few other queues, eventually coming back to the main runloop.  The catch is that when it comes back to the main runloop, it's still in UITrackingRunLoopMode.  I think that the main runloop should have come out of UITracking mode when the delegate method was completed, but when execution gets back to main runloop, it's still in that mode.  Deferring the code that kicks off the background queueing of the job from the UIScrollViewDelegate method fixes the problem, e.g `[self performSelector:@selector(sendTaskToBackQueue) withObject:nil afterDelay:0 inModes:@[NSDefaultRunLoopMode]]`.  Is it possible that the runloop mode that is used when the background task is queued back to the main thread is dependent on the mode the runloop was in when it queued the background task?**

Essentially, the only change was going from this...

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {
    // Currently in UITrackingRunLoopMode
    dispatch_async(someGlobalQueue, someBlock); 
    // Block execution hops along other queues and eventually comes back to main runloop and will still be in tracking mode.
}
```

to this

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate {
    // Currently in UITrackingRunLoopMode
    [self performSelector:@selector(backQueueTask) withObject:nil afterDelay:0 inModes:@[NSDefaultRunLoopMode]];
}
-(void)backQueueTask {
    // Currently in NSDefaultRunLoopMode
    dispatch_async(someGlobalQueue, someBlock); 
    // Hops along other queues and eventually comes back to main runloop and will still be in NSDefaultRunLoopMode.  
    // It's as if the runloop mode when execution returns was dependent on what it was when the background block was queued.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` this will call the selector **on the thread that this function is called**.

`performSelectorOnMainThread:WithObject:waitUntilDon`,this will make sure that the selector is called **on main thread**

[What is run loop](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH16-SW1):

> Run loops are part of the fundamental infrastructure associated with threads. A run loop is an event processing loop that you use to schedule work and coordinate the receipt of incoming events. The purpose of a run loop is to keep your thread busy when there is work to do and put your thread to sleep when there is none.

Comment: But what about if your executing in the context of a block that came from a different runloop?  This is the scenario I'm referring to.  For instance, I also notice that when other CoreAnimations start running again later on, the selector is eventually fired.  This leads me to believe that it's not just thread that performSelector is called on, but it's also the specific runloop that will be targeted.

Comment: A runloop belongs to a thread.You just need to understand at the point of thread. I am not sure about what you describe.You can post some example code to make it clear

Comment: I understand what a runloop is and that every NSThread has a single one for handling transaction like events.  But I also understand that you can have other runloops, and you can poll and run them, even on the same thread.  I believe this is what CoreAnimation is doing, running a separate runloop and executing my callback block in the context of its runloop, not the same primary runloop used by the main thread.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one run loop per thread, so if you're on the main thread then you're also on the main run loop.  However, a run loop can run in different modes.

There are a few things you can try to get to the bottom of the issue:

You can use `+[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]` and `+[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]` to verify that you're executing from the main thread and main run loop.

You can also use the current run loop directly with NSTimer to schedule a delayed perform-selector.  E.g.:

```
void (^completionBlock)(BOOL) = ^(BOOL finished) {

    NSCAssert([NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] == [NSRunLoop mainRunLoop], @"We're not on the main run loop");

    NSRunLoop* runLoop = [NSRunLoop mainRunLoop];

    // Immediate invocation.  
    [runLoop performSelector:@selector(someMethod) target:self argument:nil order:0 modes:@[NSDefaultRunLoopMode]];

    // Delayed invocation.  
    NSTimer* timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(someMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    [runLoop addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

};
```

Those calls are essentially equivalent to `-performSelector:withObject:` and `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`.

This allows you to confirm which run loop you're using.  If you're on the main run loop and the delayed invocation doesn't run, it's possible that the main run loop is running in a mode that doesn't service timers in the default mode.  For example, that can happen when a UIScrollView is tracking touch input.

Comment: Ah, this makes more sense now.  The path that has the problem has mode UITrackingRunLoopMode, while the happy path run loop mode is NSDefaultRunLoopMode.  The block does show it's running in the main runloop.  But even still, if the loop is in tracking mode, shouldn't the selectors be performed the next time the main loop is in the default mode?  Perhaps it won't immediately be run in the default mode again?

Comment: @JoeyCarson Yes, the timer should fire immediately when the run loop returns to default mode.  You can schedule the timer in NSRunLoopCommonModes instead of NSDefaultRunLoopMode and the timer will fire in either default or UI tracking modes.

Comment: Yes I tried that and it did work, though I don't want to put a hack that into my code.  Aside from that though, the deferred selector is never called though.  Note that if I start messing with the UI several minutes later, I have seen the deferred call run, so perhaps the main thread never returns to the default mode for whatever reason.  Something must put it in that mode and it doesn't immediately come out of it.  Should it?

Comment: @JoeyCarson If the run loop is always in UI tracking mode then that's a problem.  You can set up a run loop observer to see when you enter and exit default mode.  See CFRunLoopObserverCreateWithHandler().  Or, you can just set a simple repeating timer with, say, a 0.1 second interval that logs to the console.  If the timer is firing then you're in default mode.

Comment: I was able to trace back the original behavior to a UIKit delegate callback putting the runloop into UITracking mode.  I've updated the original question to reflect that.  It seems it had to do with what mode the main runloop was in when it kicked off a background task.  After that background task finished and queued back to the main runloop, the main runloop was still in UITracking mode.  I changed queueing the background operation to happen on the main queue (still queued to background) but the queueing itself happens in default mode instead of tracking mode.  This fixes it.  Why?

Answer (score 1):

`-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` doesn't schedule operations on a dispatch queue; it schedules it **on the run loop of the current thread**. Each thread has one run loop, but somebody has to run the run loop in order for it to execute the actions on it. So it all depends on what thread this code is run on.

If it is run on the main thread, the operation will be scheduled on the main thread's run loop. In event-based applications, `UIApplicationMain` is called in the `main` function, which runs a run loop on the main thread for the entire lifetime of the app.

If this is run on another thread that you created, then the operation will be put on that thread's run loop. But unless you explicitly run the thread's run loop, the operations scheduled on the run loop won't run.

If this is run on a GCD dispatch queue, it means it is running on some unknown thread. GCD dispatch queues manage threads internally in a way that is opaque to the user. Generally nobody would have run the run loop on such a thread, so operations scheduled on the run loop won't run. (Of course, you could explicitly run the run loop in the same place that you schedule the operation, but that would block the thread, and thus block the dispatch queue, which wouldn't make that much sense.)

Comment: This is a very comprehensive answer. Thank you sir.